# Ribbonbutton is always disabled

Tags: ribbon

I add a custom ribbon button but its always disabled. I changed the server area (in the feature) but nothing happens. The code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction
  Id="Ribbon.WikiPageTab.Share.ToPDF"
  Location="CommandUI.Ribbon">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition
         Location="Ribbon.WikiPageTab.Manage.Controls._children">
          <Button
           Id="Ribbon.WikiPageTab.Share.Controls.ToPDF"
           LabelText="Export als PDF"
           Sequence="10"
           Command="test1"
           TemplateAlias="o1"/>
        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
      <CommandUIHandlers>
        <CommandUIHandler 
          Command="test1" 
          CommandAction="javascript:alert('Hello, world');"
          EnabledScript="javascript:function JustReturnTrue() {return true;} JustReturnTrue();"
          />
      </CommandUIHandlers>
    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

Comment: which browser you are using?

Comment: Internet explorer 11 - is a registrationtyp required?

Comment: Only Title is required on the CustomAction element... try adding it. But it would also be a good idea to put in the RegistrationType to "None"

Comment: try using some other browser

Comment: The RegistrationType can´t set to "None". Also I add a title but nothing happens. In Google chrome the button is also disabled.

Answer (score 1):

If you have put that element in the feature which scope is set to "**Site**",  then add another feature, set the scope to "**Web**", add your button item in this feature, saved, deployed, enabled the new feature from site feature.

### UPDATE

Try this below **EnabledScript**:

```
EnabledScript="javascript: var JustReturnTrue = function() {return true;}; JustReturnTrue();"
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: The scope ist set to web in the main feature

Comment: Is that work for you?

Comment: I add your command but the button was also disabled. But when I add no Command in the CommandUIDefinition the Button is enabled. Is there a waiting period until the script is published?

Comment: I've tried your given code in my server, it's working properly...

Comment: When I add no command the button is enabled. When the command is "test1" the button is enabled  and show the "Hello, World" alert but when I edit (and publish) the script it shows the same alert ("Hello, World"). I don´t understand it.

Comment: It was the cache ..... After each publishing the cache must be delete. But now i have two buttons with the same name and picture....